# Camera App - Android

Tags: android, android-camera

I'm trying to build my camera app as part of my project 
I followed the documentation , and It takes a photo , store it and it Just Freeze, I need to be able to capture more photos

I tried to add `camera.startPreview();` after `mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);` but this cause an exception

this My Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    public FrameLayout preview ;
    public Button Shutter_btn;
    private Camera mCamera;
    CameraPreview mPreview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Create an instance of Camera
        mCamera = getCameraInstance();
        // Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.
        mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
        FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
        preview.addView(mPreview);

        Shutter_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        Shutter_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                TakePhoto();
            }
        });
    }

    public void TakePhoto()
    {

         PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

                    File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
                    if (pictureFile == null){

                        return;
                    }

                    try {
                        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                        fos.write(data);
                        fos.close();
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        Log.d("TAG", "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.d("TAG", "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            };
            mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);

    }

    public void CameraRelease()
    {
        if(mCamera!=null){
            mCamera.stopPreview();
            mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);

            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;             
        }

    }

    private void galleryAddPic(String ImagePath) {
        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        File f = new File(ImagePath);
        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
        this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
    }
    public  final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;

    /** Create a file Uri for saving an image or video */
    private  Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type){
          return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
    }

    /** Create a File for saving an image or video */
    private  File getOutputMediaFile(int type){
        // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
        // using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this.

        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyCameraApp");
        // This location works best if you want the created images to be shared
        // between applications and persist after your app has been uninstalled.

        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
            if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
                Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Dirrectory not been made   " +mediaStorageDir , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return null;
            }
        }
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Dirrectory not been made   " +mediaStorageDir , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE){
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
            "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
        } 
         else {
            return null;
        }

        return mediaFile;
    }


    /** A safe way to get an instance of the Camera object. */
    public  Camera getCameraInstance(){
        Camera c = null;
        try {
            c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No Camera", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();// no camera on this device
 // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
        }
        return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
    }


}
```

CameraPreview Class:

```
package ahmed.Labib.mycamera;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

/** A basic Camera preview class */
public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    public  Camera mCamera;

    public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
        super(context);
        mCamera = camera;

        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("TAG", "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // empty. Take care of releasing the Camera preview in your activity.
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
        // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.

        if (mHolder.getSurface() == null){
          // preview surface does not exist
          return;
        }

        // stop preview before making changes
        try {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e){
          // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
        }

        // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
        // reformatting changes here

        // start preview with new settings
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();

        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.d("TAG", "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

logCat

```
03-02 13:22:52.345: D/Camera-JNI(21812): (tid:21812)[MtkJNICameraContext] this:0x5bd7e628 camera->getStrongCount(3) 
03-02 13:22:52.346: D/SurfaceView(21812): checkGLSurfaceViewlLogProperty get invalid command
03-02 13:22:52.352: D/ActivityThread(21812): ACT-AM_ON_RESUME_CALLED ActivityRecord{423774e8 token=android.os.BinderProxy@42376cc0 {ahmed.Labib.mycamera/ahmed.Labib.mycamera.MainActivity}}
03-02 13:22:52.352: V/PhoneWindow(21812): DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 4 ,Parent =null, this =com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{42386b00 I.E..... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
03-02 13:22:52.361: V/PhoneWindow(21812): DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 0 ,Parent =ViewRoot{423f0800 ahmed.Labib.mycamera/ahmed.Labib.mycamera.MainActivity,ident = 0}, this =com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{42386b00 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
03-02 13:22:52.361: D/ActivityThread(21812): ACT-LAUNCH_ACTIVITY handled : 0 / ActivityRecord{423774e8 token=android.os.BinderProxy@42376cc0 {ahmed.Labib.mycamera/ahmed.Labib.mycamera.MainActivity}}
03-02 13:22:52.367: I/SurfaceView(21812): updateWindow -- onWindowVisibilityChanged, visibility = 0
03-02 13:22:52.408: E/(21812): appName=ahmed.Labib.mycamera, acAppName=/system/bin/surfaceflinger
03-02 13:22:52.408: E/(21812): 0
03-02 13:22:52.408: E/(21812): appName=ahmed.Labib.mycamera, acAppName=/system/bin/surfaceflinger
03-02 13:22:52.408: E/(21812): 0
03-02 13:22:52.412: D/GraphicBuffer(21812): create handle(0x603e5080) (w:1280, h:736, f:1)
03-02 13:22:52.414: I/MaliEGL(21812): [Mali]window_type=1, is_framebuffer=0, errnum = 0
03-02 13:22:52.414: I/MaliEGL(21812): [Mali]surface->num_buffers=4, surface->num_frames=3, win_min_undequeued=1
03-02 13:22:52.414: I/MaliEGL(21812): [Mali]max_allowed_dequeued_buffers=3
03-02 13:22:52.415: D/GraphicBuffer(21812): close handle(0x603e5080) (w:1280 h:736 f:1)
03-02 13:22:52.419: D/GraphicBuffer(21812): create handle(0x603e5e80) (w:736, h:1280, f:1)
03-02 13:22:52.421: D/OpenGLRenderer(21812): Enabling debug mode 0
03-02 13:22:52.423: D/GraphicBuffer(21812): create handle(0x608c0730) (w:768, h:768, f:1)
03-02 13:22:52.424: I/[MALI][Gralloc](21812): dlopen libsec_mem.so fail
03-02 13:22:52.425: D/OpenGLRenderer(21812): setViewport 1280x736 <0x608be490>
03-02 13:22:52.425: I/SurfaceView(21812): updateWindow -- setFrame
03-02 13:22:52.427: I/SurfaceView(21812): updateWindow -- OnPreDrawListener, mHaveFrame = true
03-02 13:22:52.428: I/SurfaceView(21812): Changes: creating=true format=true size=true visible=true left=true top=true mUpdateWindowNeeded=false mReportDrawNeeded=false redrawNeeded=false forceSizeChanged=true mVisible=false mRequestedVisible=true
03-02 13:22:52.432: I/SurfaceView(21812): Cur surface: Surface(name=null)/@0x423eb128
03-02 13:22:52.439: V/SurfaceView(21812): ahmed.Labib.mycamera.CameraPreview{423eae80 V.E..... ......ID 0,0-1110,576} got resized: w=1110 h=576, cur w=-1 h=-1
03-02 13:22:52.441: I/SurfaceView(21812): New surface: Surface(name=null)/@0x423eb1f8, vis=true, frame=Rect(85, 139 - 1195, 715)
03-02 13:22:52.442: I/SurfaceView(21812): Callback --> surfaceCreated
03-02 13:22:52.442: I/SurfaceView(21812): surfaceCreated callback +
03-02 13:22:53.146: I/SurfaceView(21812): surfaceCreated callback -
03-02 13:22:53.146: I/SurfaceView(21812): surfaceChanged -- format=4 w=1110 h=576
03-02 13:22:53.146: I/SurfaceView(21812): surfaceChanged callback +
03-02 13:22:55.035: I/SurfaceView(21812): surfaceChanged callback -
03-02 13:22:55.035: I/SurfaceView(21812): surfaceRedrawNeeded
03-02 13:22:55.035: I/SurfaceView(21812): finishedDrawing
03-02 13:22:55.040: V/SurfaceView(21812): Layout: x=85 y=139 w=1110 h=576, frame=Rect(0, 0 - 1110, 576)
03-02 13:22:55.041: I/Choreographer(21812): Skipped 165 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-02 13:22:55.046: I/SurfaceView(21812): updateWindow -- OnPreDrawListener, mHaveFrame = true
03-02 13:22:55.047: I/SurfaceView(21812): Changes: creating=false format=false size=false visible=false left=false top=false mUpdateWindowNeeded=true mReportDrawNeeded=true redrawNeeded=false forceSizeChanged=false mVisible=true mRequestedVisible=true
03-02 13:22:55.047: I/SurfaceView(21812): Cur surface: Surface(name=null)/@0x423eb128
03-02 13:22:55.052: I/SurfaceView(21812): New surface: Surface(name=null)/@0x423eb1f8, vis=true, frame=Rect(85, 139 - 1195, 715)
03-02 13:22:55.052: I/SurfaceView(21812): surfaceRedrawNeeded
03-02 13:22:55.053: I/SurfaceView(21812): finishedDrawing
03-02 13:22:55.054: V/SurfaceView(21812): Layout: x=85 y=139 w=1110 h=576, frame=Rect(0, 0 - 1110, 576)
03-02 13:22:55.069: D/OpenGLRenderer(21812): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 1280.00, 736.00) opaque 1 <0x608be490>
03-02 13:22:55.083: D/OpenGLRenderer(21812): finish <0x608be490>
03-02 13:22:55.127: V/InputMethodManager(21812): onWindowFocus: null softInputMode=32 first=true flags=#1810100
03-02 13:22:55.128: V/InputMethodManager(21812): START INPUT: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{42386b00 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-1280,736} ic=null tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@424143c8 controlFlags=#104
03-02 13:22:55.138: I/SurfaceView(21812): updateWindow -- UPDATE_WINDOW_MSG
03-02 13:22:55.152: I/SurfaceView(21812): updateWindow -- setFrame
03-02 13:22:55.154: I/SurfaceView(21812): updateWindow -- OnPreDrawListener, mHaveFrame = true
03-02 13:22:55.159: D/GraphicBuffer(21812): create handle(0x60ca4738) (w:736, h:1280, f:1)
03-02 13:22:55.164: D/OpenGLRenderer(21812): prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 1280.00, 736.00) opaque 1 <0x608be490>
03-02 13:22:55.166: D/OpenGLRenderer(21812): finish <0x608be490>
03-02 13:23:16.506: I/View(21812): Touch down dispatch to android.widget.Button{423b7070 VFED..C. ........ 1088,255-1195,362 #7f090042 app:id/button3}, event = MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, id[0]=0, x[0]=37.12097, y[0]=55.464417, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=82397060, downTime=82397060, deviceId=2, source=0x1002 }
03-02 13:23:16.582: I/View(21812): Touch up dispatch to android.widget.Button{423b7070 VFED..C. ...P.... 1088,255-1195,362 #7f090042 app:id/button3}, event = MotionEvent { action=ACTION_UP, id[0]=0, x[0]=37.12097, y[0]=55.464417, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=82397141, downTime=82397060, deviceId=2, source=0x1002 }
03-02 13:23:16.583: V/Provider/Settings(21812): from db cache, name = sound_effects_enabled , value = 0
03-02 13:23:17.656: I/Choreographer(21812): Skipped 66 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-02 13:23:18.486: D/Camera-JNI(21812): Allocating callback buffer
03-02 13:23:18.493: I/CameraFramework(21812): handleMessage: 256
03-02 13:23:18.569: D/GraphicBuffer(21812): create handle(0x60c9d8e0) (w:640, h:59, f:1)
03-02 13:23:22.006: D/GraphicBuffer(21812): close handle(0x60c9d8e0) (w:640 h:59 f:1)
```

I need help to know what's wrong

Comment: where is your logcat?

Comment: Question updated ... thanks

Comment: thats not your application log

Comment: updated .. but this all what I can catch because it's scroll fast

Answer (score 0):

I Figure what was wrong 
I Have to add `mCamera.startPreview();` in the `onPictureTaken()` it self not after the

```
mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
```

update `onPictureTaken()` :

```
PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

                    File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
                    if (pictureFile == null){

                        return;
                    }

                    try {
                        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                        fos.write(data);
                        fos.close();
                        galleryAddPic(pictureFile.getPath());
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        Log.d("TAG", "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.d("TAG", "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                            mCamera.startPreview();

                    }
                }
            };
```